# Filtering a list with data loaded from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to filter a list with the `<li>` elements loaded from the server. However, nothing is appearing. Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-split-theme="b" data-split-icon="plus" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search for courses..." data-inset="true" id="loadList">
    <!-- Data below loaded from php (server) -->
    <li id="clist">
    <a href="#abc">
    <h2>$row['Name']</h2>
    </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Data from php finished -->
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $.get(
    "loadAllCourses.php",
    function( data ){
        $('#loadList').html( data );
        .listview( 'refresh' );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like jQuery mobile. Can you confirm this? If so, you should add it as a tag so that it appears to the jqm audience as well.

Comment: What is `.listview( 'refresh' );` supposed to be chained to? There's a semi-colon prior to that from `.html(data);`

Comment: @Code Maverick omg..yes it shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though you have a typo. You have `.html( data );.listview( 'refresh' );`

Should be:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.get(
    "loadAllCourses.php",
    function( data ){
        $( '#loadList' )
            .html( data )
            .listview( 'refresh' );
    });
});
</script>
```